# Installing scrlttr2 – Koma-Script ‘letter’ class in LYX

Tags: lyx, miktex, installing, koma-script, scrlttr2

I am having problem with installation of scrlttr2 – Koma-Script ‘letter’ class. I am unable to install it. I needed help on how to install it. I am using Windows Machine,my Miktex is located in the folder `D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9` and Lyx is in `D:\Program Files\LYX`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Lyx comes with KOMA-script letter out of the box, no need to install it, as far as I know! Why do you assume scrlettr2.cls is not installed?

Comment: The MikTeX package to install is `koma-script` to get the whol KOMA-bundle.